# Rejection Region. T- distribution.

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Let's assume that we have computed T-ratio for some data:
$t = -0.9054 $ And our $\alpha = 0.05 $
Now, we would like find rejection region for this left-tail. The author wrote, that rejection region is: $(-\infty, -z_{\alpha}]$. Where $z_\alpha $ is $\alpha$ -quantile in normal distribution.

I don't understand why did author use Normal Distribution, after all t comes from T-Distribution.

Thanks in advance.